# Converting Array object to string using dataweave 2.0

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I am trying to convert Array object to String using Dataweave-2.0 with the below input and output.

Input :

```
[
{"Name":"Sam","language":"Java","Id":"101"},
{"Name":"Ryan","language":"C","Id":"104"},
{"Name":"Sarah","language":"C","Id":"109"},
{"Name":"Rose","language":"Java","Id":"103"}
]
```

My output should be:
`Name Sam   language Java Id 101 Name Ryan  language C    Id 104 Name Sarah language C    Id 109 Name Rose  language Java Id 103`

I am unable to get the expected output.
Any help is appreciated in advance. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
(payload flatMap ($ pluck ($$ ++ " " ++ $))) joinBy  "   "
```

---

Output

```
"Name Sam   language Java   Id 101   Name Ryan   language C   Id 104   Name Sarah   language C   Id 109   Name Rose   language Java   Id 103"
```

Comment: Yes, its working. Thanks a lot, Stevens. One more question - Is there a possibility to remove the quotes in the output?

Comment: Yes, You can achieve above without double quote by keeping output type:  output application/java or text/plain

Comment: Got it. Thanks Manish

Answer (score 0):

```
%dw 2.0 
output text/plain 
---
( 
   payload map ((item, index) ->item mapObject ((value, key, index) ->{ 
              "str": key ++ " "++ value 
               }))reduce ((item, accumulator) ->accumulator ++ item)
).*str joinBy " "
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).